# Standard ML unusual datatype

Tags: types, sml

for the following function,

```
fun foo (x, y) = 
  if x > 5 then y[1]
  else y[0];
```

standard ML shows the data type of y to be (int list → 'a).
Should it not be ('a list) instead?

Comment: Start your interpreter and enter `[1];`and you will see `val it = [1] : int list`. If you enter `[1,2,3][1];`, you will see an error message. (Using the interpreter for exploration is a very good idea.)

Answer (score 1):

We don't use `[]` to access list elements in SML like we do in, say, Python. This

```
y[1]
```

is seen as

```
y [1]
```

i.e. the *function* `y` applied to a single argument, which happens to be the list containing the number `1`. Which is why the inferred type is "a function that accepts a list of integers".

In ML, we index into a list the same way we do everything else: [with a function](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/list.html). There's no special syntax; it's just a function.

```
fun foo (x, y) = if x > 5 then List.nth (y, 1)
                 else List.nth (y, 0);
```

Comment: As an addendum, given that lists in SML do not support constant-time random access, indexing this way is rarely used.